# Issue with scope while upgrade in rails4.2.6 from 4.1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Issue in rail 4.2.6 during upgrade from `rails4.1.9` to `4.2.6`=>

I am trying to find those record from a table in which id is same as `parent_id`.
So I have written a scope

```
scope :parent_record, ->{ where(parent_id: self[:id]) }
```

When I am using this scope and calculating

```
  self.all.parent_record
```

it returns  `"# ActiveRecord::Relation []>"`

While in rails 4.1.9 it returns -

```
#ActiveRecord::Relation [#Category id: 6, name: "Business Disruption", description: "", parent_id: 6, status: "a", target_risk: nil, lock_target_risk: false].
```

Ruby version - ruby-2.0.0-p598

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Can you try `scope :parent_record, ->{ where(parent_id: self.id) }`

Comment: already tried it and throw error -*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `id' for #<Class:0x0000000919ae98>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really surprised that this worked in Rails `4.1.9`. Because `self` would return the class and not an individual instance in the context of an scope. Therefore `self[:id]` doesn't really makes sense.

I would write something like this to find all records which `parent_id` matches their own `id`:

```
scope :own_parent, -> { where('id = parent_id') }
```

Comment: i did it already as scope :parent_record, ->{ where("#{table_name}.id = #{table_name}.parent_id"]) }